# Is the geometric result of an intersection between two valid JTS polygons guaranteed to be valid?

Tags: geometry, intersection, overlay, jts-topology-suite

If I have two overlapping [JTS Polygon](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html) objects, which are [valid](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#isValid--), is the result of an [intersection](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#intersection-org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry-) operation between the two meant to be guaranteed to be a valid geometry?

Obviously this guarantee could be broken due to bugs but that is not what I am asking.

Note: There is a [sibling question about the Simple Feature standard](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449343/is-the-geometric-result-of-an-intersection-between-two-valid-polygons-guaranteed), which JTS is based upon. This question here is from the perspective of the software implementation in JTS, not about what the standard might say, i.e. does *JTS* give a guarantee on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the contract of the overlay operations (including intersection) is that the result should always be valid, if the input is.

In fact, this is the contract for most geometry operations in JTS, since it's much more useful to produce valid geometry for use in further operations.

The only situations where this might not hold are due to bugs (which should be reported so they can be fixed) and possibly some geometric robustness failures.