# Is the geometric result of an intersection between two valid PostGIS polygons guaranteed to be valid?

Tags: postgis, geometry, intersection, overlay

If I have two overlapping PostGIS Polygon geometry objects, which are [valid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html), is the result of an [intersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) operation between the two meant to be guaranteed to be a valid geometry?

Obviously this guarantee could be broken due to bugs but that is not what I am asking.

Note: There is a [sibling question about JTS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449344/is-the-geometric-result-of-an-intersection-between-two-valid-jts-polygons-guaran), which GEOS is based upon, which PostGIS uses. This question here is from the perspective of a PostGIS end-user, i.e. does *PostGIS* give a guarantee on this.

Comment: As open source code, PostGIS offers no warranty. One would certainly *hope* correct results would be obtained, but it is difficult to prove perfect results from all cases in real software.

Comment: This question is not about warranty in terms of law but guarantee in terms of algorithmic design.

Comment: It's still more philosophical than practical.

Comment: I learned to be extremely wary when transforming geometries (or worst, geographies) having an inner ring touching the outer ring at a single point, with no vertex on the outer ring (default in PG), as sometimes the "contact" point ends up being outside of the outer ring, which is invalid.

Comment: I dare say, and this is true for all your questions but the one about the actual formal definition of feature, in *theory* this is the logic conclusion, but in practice and with finite numerical representations limiting vector math, you _will_ be able to find plenty of cases where an intersection fails. Even if e.g. the JTS makes a tremendously well attempt to be geometrically robust.

Comment: There might be safeguards written in the tools that check validity before presenting the result to the user and raise an error or similar otherwise. JTS or PostGIS already have measures to determine if geometries are valid. Their overlay algorithms might assert validity and thus there might be implicit (but currently not documented) guarantees for validity. To be honest I don't really understand the controversy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the contract of the overlay operations (including intersection) is that the result should always be valid, if the input is.

In fact, this is the contract for most geometry operations in PostGIS, since it's much more useful to produce valid geometry for use in further operations.

The only situations where this might not hold are due to bugs (which should be reported so they can be fixed) and possibly some geometric robustness failures.